# UNION Statement Showing Inconsistent Results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query that consists of two SELECT statements which are UNION'ed together. When run individually they the first SELECT returns 10 records and the second SELECT returns 1 record, so when I UNION the two SELECTs I would expect to get 11 records returned but this is not the case, I'm only getting 9 records.

Due to the nature of the SQL I can't actually post it here but it consists of numerous JOINS across 5 tables. Everything being returned is correct and valid.

Just wondering if anyone has seen this issue occur when UNION'ing two SELECT statements and if anyone has any advice on what could be the cause or even point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: you should not be expecting exactly 11 records. UNION will "merge" duplicates into one row, so you should be expecting MAX 11 records. If you get 9, it probably means that they are duplicates in first 10 records... Can you try with UNION ALL ? And / or try a DISTINCT on your first query, to see how many rows you get.

Comment: We can't help you if you won't post the code. `UNION` should not behave that way, so the code will be critical to determining the issue. I would suggest creating a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with code that shows the issue - it doesn't have to be your exact code - just something that exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks for that, works perfectly now, wasn't aware about the ALL option. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) remove duplicates by default. To prevent duplicates from being removed [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) should be used.

Quoting the documentation:

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Oracle applies an implicit distinct clause to the result of a union. You may want to check whether the results of your separate queries include common items.

If you do not want this behavior, you need to use the UNION ALL clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `UNION ALL` instead of only `UNION`. UNION only returns distinct rows. [Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm).